# MongoDb Error deserializing F# List

Tags: mongodb, serialization, f#

So I have a simple object

```
type DbObject() = 
    member val Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString() with get, set
    member val Name = "" with get, set
type Item() =
    inherit DbObject()
    member val Description = "" with get, set
    member val Refs : list<string> = [] with get, set
```

This works just fine when I insert it into my MongoDB database, but whenever I try to receive it back I get the following error.

```
System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the Material property of class Item: Type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method. ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' does not have a suitable constructor or Add method.
```

I am guessing that the problem is that FSharpList does not have a deserializer, but how come it can serialize just fine, shouldn't it work both ways? Is the only way to make it work to customize a serializer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# lists are immutable singly linked lists, but the library, judging by the error message, expects to find a mutable list with an `Add` method on it. To satisfy that, just use a `ResizeArray` - it's F# synonym for `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`.

```
    member val Refs : ResizeArray<string> ...
```